# What does this mysql statement mean?

Tags: mysql

Could someone please tell me what the values produced by the command below represent?

```
select name, current_date - date_of_birth as age from name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It selects `name` column, then it calculates the `current_date - date_of_birth` expression (that is - `current_date` value (which contains the current date) is subtracted by `date_of_birth` column) which is then stored as `age` column from the `name` table.

Comment: This is my first time using mysql. Thank you!